# T-SQL: Trigger that runs right before the end of a modifying transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, triggers

### Problem statement

I have a view for recursively collecting and aggregating infos from 3 different large to very large tables. This view itself needs quite a time to execute but is needed in many select statements and is executed quite often.

The resulting view, however, is very small (a few dozend results in 2 columns).

All updating actions typically start a transaction, execute many thousand INSERTs and then commit the transaction. This does not occur very frequently, but if something is written to the database it is usually a large amount of data.

**What I tried**

1. As the view is small, does not change frequently and is read often, I thought of creating an indexed view. However, sadly you can not create an indexed view with CTEs or even recursive CTEs.
2. To 'emulate' a indexed or materialized view, I thought about writing a trigger that executes the view and stores the results into a table every time one of the base tables get modified. However, I guess this would take forever if a large amout of entries are UPDATEed or INSERTed and the trigger runs for each INSERT/UPDATE statement on those tables, even if they are inside a single transaction.

### Actual question

Is it possible to write a trigger that runs **once** before commiting and after the last insert/update statement of a transaction has finished and only if any of the statements has changed any of the three tables?

Comment: Directly, no, triggers run once per triggering statement.  Indirectly, you could have all of your INSERT's insert into a temporary table and then INSERT them all together from the #temp table into the real table, resulting in one trigger firing for that table.  But if you are writing to multiple tables, you would still have the same problem.  The SOP way to address this is to have a stored procedure handle everything up front instead of a Trigger trying to catch everything on the back-side.

Comment: When the base tables are modified, is a single INSERT or UPDATE statement used that effects many rows or are many granular statements used?

Comment: Well you could write triggers that record each time there's a data change in each table. Then write a job that checks for any changes every few minutes or so and updates a table using your view accordingly. That way it doesn't fire too many times but your data is up to date with in a certain period of time.

Comment: @Ben Gribaudo: there are many granular statements, i.e. insertion of several thousand records into one table as one 'batch' transaction.

Comment: @Stephan: thanks for the idea, but in this application data consistency is crucial. the data _must_ be consistent at all times and therefore with the commit of each transaction. An 'eventually consistent' approach is unfortunately not possible here.

Comment: As an alternative solution: is it possible to create an indexed view with a recursive select without using recursive CTEs? Why are CTEs not allowed in indexed views in the first place?

Comment: Are you able to edit the insert/update queries?

Comment: Recursive CTE's are the only non-procedural way to do a recursive select in SQL Server.  CTE's are probably not allowed, because after you take away all of the things you cannot use in the view, there's not much need for CTE's left, so they likely figured "*why bother with the extra work to check CTE's too?*"

Comment: If data consistency is important, then I'd recommend that you follow the SOP approach that I outlined above: Use a stored procedure that dumps all of the changes into #temp tables first, then starts a transaction, then makes the changes, then does the work you wanted in a trigger, then commits the transaction.  This is almost always how something like this is done correctly.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: thanks, that seemed like the best way to approach this and I implemented it like this. works like a charm! Can you put that into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no direct way to make a trigger that runs right before the end of a transaction.  DML Triggers run once per triggering DML statement (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`), and there's no other kind of trigger related to data modification.

Indirectly, you could have all of your INSERT's insert into a temporary table and then INSERT them all together from the #temp table into the real table, resulting in one trigger firing for that table. But if you are writing to multiple tables, you would still have the same problem.

The SOP (Standard Operating Practice) way to address this is to have a stored procedure handle everything up front instead of a Trigger trying to catch everything on the back-side.

If data consistency is important, then I'd recommend that you follow the SOP approach based in a stored procedure that I mentioned above.  Here's a hi-level outline of this approach:

1. Use a stored procedure that dumps all of the changes into #temp tables first,
2. then start a transaction,
3. then make the changes, moving data/changes from your #temp table(s) into your actual tables,
4. then do the follow-up work you wanted in a trigger.  If these are consistency checks, then if they fail, you should rollback the transaction.
5. Otherwise, it then commits the transaction.

This is almost always how something like this is done correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If your view is small and queried frequently and your underline tables are rarely changed, you don't need a "view". Instead you need a summary table with the same result of the view and updated by your triggers on each underline table.

A trigger is triggered every time you have data modification (insert, delete and update) but one modification will only trigger once, whether it updates one record or one million rows. You don't need worry about the size of update. Instead the frequency of updating is your concern.

If your have a procedure periodically insert large number of rows, or updates large number of rows one by one, you can change the procedure and disable the triggers before the update so the summary table will be updated only before the end of procedure, where you can call the same "sum" procedure and enable those triggers.

If you HAVE TO keep the "summary" up-to-date all the time, even during large number of transactions (i doubt it's very helpful or practical, if your view is slow to execute),  you can disable those triggers, do some calculation by yourself after each transaction, update the summary table after each transaction, in your procedure.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer, that is basically what my solution now looks like: I call the procedure that updates the summary table (works like kind of a materialized view) via a procedure right at the end of the transaction of INSERTs.